# Trigger an email to admin when new user registers in a Django app

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-registration

I'd like to trigger a simple plaintext email to admin(s) when a new user registers for my Django app. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [a post save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) for this. For example:

```
# <app>/signals.py:

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django.core.mail import send_mail

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def send_email_to_admin(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_mail(
            '<Subject>User {} has been created'.format(instance.username),
            '<Body>A new user has been created',
            'from@example.com',
            ['admin@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )


# <app>/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
   name = 'app_name'
   verbose_name = _('app_name')

   def ready(self):
     import .signals  # noqa
```

Here, I am using [**`django's mail sending functionality`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail) as example, if you are using that then please make sure you have properly configured the settings.

Comment: Thank you! Since this is a project level setting (meaning it's not tied to a particular app, but the project itself), where should i put app.py?

Comment: sorry, it should be `apps.py` and they exist in every django app. You can add the ready function to any of the `apps.py`, just make sure it is in same directory as signals.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I started a new app and just put the apps.py logic and the signals.py, but at user registration, it's not triggering. I also tried using djangp all-auths signals, but those aren't triggering (not seeing my print() in console either). And yes, put the new app in settings.py

Comment: Got it. The missing piece was adding the `default_app_config` to my `__init__.py`